# Who attacked Dr Jacoby and why?

Tags: plot-explanation, twin-peaks

At the end of Season 1 of Twin Peaks, there are a lot of things happening. One of them is that Donna, James, and Maddy lure Dr Jacoby to the park making him think Maddy is Laura. As he is sneaking to the park, he is attacked by someone who we do not see.

My question: who is this and why did they attack Dr. Jacoby?

As far as I know it is never revealed in the show.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems the official answer is Leland. From the [IMDb FAQ](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0098936/faq#.2.1.8):

> This was never explicitly revealed onscreen. However, producer Mark Frost later revealed in an interview that Dr. Jacoby's attacker was 'the same person who killed Laura Palmer.'
>
> Therefore, it had to be Leland, while possessed by Bob. This is strongly indicated by Jacoby's reference to smelling burnt engine oil, a smell associated with the killer.

When Leland senses that Maddy is sneaking out, the implication is that he follows her and that's how he finds Jacoby. But as to *why* he attacks Jacoby, this is never clarified. Apparently, the creators simply tried to cram as many cliffhangers as possible in the season 1 finale. [From the same FAQ](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0098936/faq#.2.1.7):

> During the filming of the first season finale, Frost and Lynch, fearful that the show would not be renewed, decided to **place every character in peril**, so that no matter what characters a fan happened to like, they would have a vested interest in seeing the series renewed.

Comment: Huh, I must've missed that when I was watching recently. I remember the mention of the burnt engine oil but I totally don't remember it being indicated as a connection to Bob.

Comment: It's possible it was meant to be someone else (there's a mysterious man in a similar ski mask in episode 2 that I don't think is ever mentioned again) and they scrapped it and went with Leland. BTW, the burnt oil smell is raised in at least one more episode (the [finale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Episode_29_%28Twin_Peaks%29)).